# Is it possible to invoke a static method by using objects in Python?

Tags: python, object, static-methods

I am new in Python. I have one doubt regarding static methods in Python. I know that we can invoke a static method by using class name (`ClassName.StaticMethodName`) and it's not possible by using objects (like `objName.StaticMethodName`).

But I am able to invoke a static method by using objects.
This is my code. I can call the method `ParentStaticMethod()` by using object.
How is this possible?

```
class Parent:

    def __init__(self):
        print 'Parent Class Constructor'

    def ParentMethod(self):
        print 'Parent Method'

    @staticmethod
    def ParentStaticMethod():
        print 'Parent Static Method'

pObj=Parent()
pObj.ParentMethod()
pObj.ParentStaticMethod()
```

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing stopping you from using an object instance to invoke a static method. See the [documentation for the `staticmethod` decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod):

> It can be called either on the class (such as `C.f()`) or on an instance (such as `C().f()`). The instance is ignored except for its class.